# SQL Server stored procedure : variable with apostrophe in a select statement not retrieving values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spBlogPostGet]
    @Id int NULL,
    @ParentBlogTitle varchar(150) NULL
AS
    IF @Id > 0
    BEGIN   
        SELECT * 
        FROM tblBlogPosts 
        WHERE Id = @Id;
    END
    ELSE IF @ParentBlogTitle IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN       
        SELECT * 
        FROM tblBlogPosts 
        WHERE ParentBlogTitle = @ParentBlogTitle;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM tblBlogPosts 
        ORDER BY(DateCreated);
    END
```

And I'm trying to test with:

```
use MyDb

exec spBlogPostGet
          @Id = 0, @ParentBlogTitle = 'some dude''s Blog';
```

I have a blog post with the parent blog title "Some Dude's Blog" but my stored procedure is not retrieving this row. If I attempt to retrieve a row that doesn't have an apostrophe in its name it'll select the named row.

I can't seem to find a solution to this - I have a very basic understanding of SQL and would appreciate some guidance.

Thank you

Comment: Does apostrophe appear in that blog title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... aaaaaand I'm an idiot. I was passing my value via an ajax request and obtaining the text from a dropdown list instead of the selected value. My sql table was showing the correct value, but when stepping through my code I was actually passing the entire contents of the dropdown list, so no wonder my query wasn't returning anything.